# Select all keys in sub-sub objects

Tags: json, jq

I don't get how jq works. I'm trying hard but I just don't get it. See below how I now create a jq query.

So this is my JSON, and I just want to extract the **name** keys in all the sub-objects

```
{
  "checkpassword": {
    "checkpassword": {
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "checkpassword",
          "exists": "true",
          "running": "true"
        }
      ],
      "projectdir": "true",
      "nginxdef": "true"
    }
  },
  "reverse_proxy": {
    "reverse_proxy": {
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "reverse_proxy",
          "exists": "true",
          "running": "true"
        }
      ],
      "projectdir": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

I gave up trying by myself, I'm wasting time on it.
I feel lots of users are in the same situation.

Please any help is appreciated.

.

NB: this is how I develop my queries:

```
root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '.[] | select( any(.name)'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select( any(.name)
jq: 1 compile error
 root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '.[] | select( any(".name")'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select( any(".name")
jq: 1 compile error
 root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '.[] | select( any("name")'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select( any("name")
jq: 1 compile error
 root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '.[] | select(any("name")'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select(any("name")
jq: 1 compile error
 root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '. | select(any("name")'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. | select(any("name")
jq: 1 compile error
 root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '. | select(any(".name")'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. | select(any(".name")
jq: 1 compile error
 root@priv  …/newProject   master  san_listProjects | jq -r '. | select(any(.name)'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. | select(any(.name)
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: So, you want to extract **all** `name`s? Or are there ones to be excluded in your actual input?

Comment: Well, I'm actually going to remove some, but with a grep -v, it will be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is neither of `.` or `.[]` lets you access object keys nested at the level `.name` key is present. Also you have a missing close `)` for all the invocations of `select` function.

There are multiple ways to get this done. One way is map the path leading up to the `name` key and get the value of that path

```
(paths | select( .[-1] == "name")) as $path | getpath($path)
```

<sup>[jqplay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sIPGPDgxq5)</sup>

or as noted in the comments, just use the recursive descent builtin `recurse` and select objects with fields containing `.name` key

```
recurse | select(has("name")?).name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unless someone guided me, how on earth would I find by myself? 
How did you find yourself? How did you get the logic?

Comment: @Bibelo: 1) Start looking at the jq manual - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/. 2) Try searching the SO forum for similar questions